# Where are Minecraft Bedrock Edition worlds stored?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to share my Minecraft world with my friend, but I cannot seem to find the world, where are they stored?

Answer (score -1):

### Windows

Replace "User_Name" with your actual account username:
`C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds`

My username is "Admin", so for me it is:
[image: Minecraft Bedrock Edition Worlds]

### Android

`/storage/emulated/0/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`

### iOS

It could be at various places depending on your version of the game. It's one of these:

- `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/minecraftpe/Documents/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`
- `Apps/com.mojang.minecraftpe/Documents/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/`
- `/On My iPhone/Minecraft/games/com.mojang/`

### Xbox One

You can find the world files in your AppData folder, under the path:
`%LOCALAPPDATA%PackagesMicrosoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbweLocalStategamescom.mojangminecraftWorlds`

### PlayStation

On PlayStation, your worlds are stored on the cloud

Comment: Thought I'd add: to access files on your iOS or iPadOS devices, you'll need to use the Files app (loaded by default on your device iirc), then click on `On My iPhone` or `On My iPad`. From there, minecraft will be stored in a folder sharing the same name.

NOTE: Files will load whatever folder or file you were looking at previously, so you'll need to navigate back as far as you can to access `On My iPhone/iPad`